# Excel VBA automate data entry in a web

Tags: excel, vba

```
 Sub Godmode()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "http://charterweb.santanderuk.gs.corp/CharterServiceChain/default.aspx"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    IE.document.getElementById("M_E_ctlPartField208_V").Value = "test"


End Sub
```

> I am always getting an error saying; method document of object iwebbrowser2 failed

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the element ID, then as a second command assign a value to that element.

```
elementIwantToChange = IE.document.getElementById("M_E_ctlPartField208_V")

elementIwantToChange.Value = "test"
```

Also you should test whether the element ID returned is "null"

Comment: How would test whethe the element id returned is null? I’m queite new to this

Comment: ```If IsNull(elementIwantToChange)```     [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnull-function)